# Need to get css selector from SitePrism WebElement in RUBY CAPYBARA?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, site-prism

I need to retrieve css selector from SitePrism WebElement inside my Automation Script. Below is a WebElement in SitePrism.

```
element :fld_web_element, "#unique_id .some_class_name"
```

If i want to retrive XPath from this webelement, i can do this below which will return Xpath for that element:

```
@page.fld_web_element.path
```

But if i want to retrieve css selector("#unique_id .some_class_name") in my script. How can i do this? Looking for something like this.

```
@page.fld_web_element.css
```

Need your help....I am using SitePrism Capybara Ruby Framework.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to provide that - and there really can't be unless Site-Prism provides a way to access the selector (find_args) you originally passed it.  You could attempt to build a unique CSS selector for the element by traversing  back up the tree and build a css selector using nth-child that would refer to the element but it'll almost never be the same selector you passed to `element`